# spring boot database connection for master and slave databases

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds, read-replication

I have spring boot microservices running on AWS ECS. I am using aws rds postgress and spring boot. I have 3 microservices and so 3 different databases.. Now I want to implement read replica of rds in my spring boot application. How to configure so read operation will goes thru read replica and master for write operation..

Comment: Why don't you do that in AWS? https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/read-replicas/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, this is of creating read replica. But once i create it, how to make connection from source code? does it automatically make select query from read replica instead of master table? don't we have to change connection in source code?